# Apache Cassandra as a message data store for ActiveMQ

Tags: cassandra, activemq-classic

Can I use Apache Cassandra as a message data store for ActiveMQ?

The reason I am exploring this option is we have to have our application on cluster and provide scalability and failover :

- KahaDb - Can be clustered but if the disk space goes out we cannot be failover.
- MySQL / another RDBMS - point of failure is the DB.
- Cassandra is in-memory database and also provides clustering.

Can someone help me understand if my reasons are correct and that Cassandra can help us persist message better than KahaDb, Database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.  The [QSandra](https://github.com/ticktock/qsandra) project on GitHub has implemented an ActiveMQ message store on top of Cassandra.

Comment: Is there anything more up to date than QSandra? This project does not appear to active anymore and the Maven repo is not even there anymore. :/